# Semantic UI React -- Can't Set Key Property on Table Row

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm displaying a list of results from an API in a Table using Semantic UI React.

The table displays correctly but getting the following error:

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
```

I'm mapping an array and displaying like so:

```
 <Table.Row key={card.id}>
```

When i look at the html results, there is no key in the TR.

if i change the table row to `id={card.id}`or any other variable, the results show, but not `key`

Is there something different i need to do with Semantic UI?  I didn't see anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

I figured this out.  Posting for anyone that might have a similar issue.

I have a React Fragment right before the Table Row and figured out that it also needs a key.  Thus, this was solved by doing the following:

```
 <React.Fragment key={card.id}>
              <Table.Row key={card.id}>
```

Comment: You shouldn't need a key on the row, if you have one on the Fragment?

Comment: Yep you are right, figured that out afterwards.  Fixing code now